# Generate html2canvas image into bootstrap modal

Tags: html, html2canvas

I'm trying to generate the image to the bootstrap's modal. But it is not showing. Please see my code below.

```
$('#generateImageReport').on('click', function(){
   $('#generate').on('click', function(){
       html2canvas($("#capture")).then(canvas => {
         $('#imageReportModal .modal-body').html(canvas)
       });
   });
});
```